# Rest assured equivalent in Python for Rest API automation testing

Tags: python, rest, testing, automation

in Java there is a [rest-assured](http://rest-assured.io/) framework to make the API requests and validate the responses with various ways.
Is there any alternative in Python?
Or I should use the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library to make the API calls and validate the responses e.g using JsonPath, XmlPath and other libraries.

Answer (score 5):

In order to simulate the same functionality as in Java's rest-assured, you can use:

**Option 1**

[requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module along with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/index.html)

**Option 2**

Use an available module [pyhttptest](https://github.com/slaily/pyhttptest)
Here you just need to define your test-cases and request in a json file and run all your test cases using command line

**And Last**

> My favorite and recommended one is [pyresttest](https://github.com/svanoort/pyresttest)

pyresttest is tool for testing RESTful HTTP requests. It’s written in Python (hence the py prefix) but unless you intend to write extensions this does not require any Python programming. It will work just fine in a Ruby, Go, Node, or PHP project.

As a command line tool it works by specifying a root URL (host) address and then the path to a YAML configuration file. The configuration file enumerates a list of URLs to request and tests against the expected status code.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django or Django Rest Framework For developing your REST APIs then you can use the django.test.Client. It helps you simulate requests with data defined in your application. You can write a shell script which executes these files on a production server and then use the results to make sure code changes don't break any existing code.

```
from django.test import Client
c = Client()

# Call a POST request endpoint with data
response = c.post("/login/", {"username": "john", "password": "smith"})
status_code = response.status_code
if status_code==200:
    print("wow test case passed")
```

You can find the complete documentation from the django's official docs from this link
[official_docs_test_client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for some simple API tests for your endpoints, check `ReqFlow` package. It uses a similar approach to `RestAssured`.

https://reqflow.org/